# Erro de leitura de 'getContext' ao herdar a classe 'createjs.Sprite'

Tags: javascript, easeljs, spritesheet

Iniciei o desenvolvimento de um jogo em HTML5 com o uso da biblioteca [EaselJS](http://www.createjs.com/#!/EaselJS). Ao criar uma classe chamada `Bot`, que conterá o código do robô utilizado no jogo, obtive o seguinte erro:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getContext' of undefined
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Pelo que eu entendo, esse erro ocorre quando o JavaScript executa antes do *canvas* ter sido inicializado. Mas não me parece ser esse o caso (a instância da classe `Bot` é criada apenas na chamada de `handleImageLoad`, após a imagem do *sprite sheet* ser carregada na chamada de `init` efetuada no evento `onLoad` do corpo do HTML).

Depurando, parece-me que o erro ocorre ao tentar criar o `SpriteSheet` (dentro da chamada de `initialize`). Coloquei o [código no JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/luigivieira/P9HFP/12/). Alguém consegue identificar onde eu estou errando?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Passe sua imagem ao construtor de `Bot`, e esse erro não ocorrerá mais:

```
function handleImageLoad() {
  oBot = new Bot(oBotImage); // << mude aqui!
  oStage.addChild(oBot);
  oStage.update();
}
```

Note que, como `handleImageLoad` é chamado no contexto da imagem, passando `this` tem o mesmo efeito:

```
  oBot = new Bot(this);
```

Comment: Cara, sem sombra de dúvida, era isso mesmo (que erro bobo que eu fui cometer, heim?). Obrigado! :)

Comment: Essas coisas acontecem... Às vezes precisamos de um [pato de borracha](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging).

Comment: Hehe Bem por ai. Valeu de novo! []s